# playing images sequentially in ios

Tags: ios, video

Suppose i have  multiple frames from a video . I would like to play these frames  in a movie player . These frames can change at any point of time . So it should be like a callback that should request each frame and program provides the frame to player as a response to call back.

Is it possible in IOS?

Please guide me in right direction in order to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

mia.

Comment: Saw a down vote here. dont know whats the reason to get it down voted. its just a direct question ... we can provide source for a video ... my doubt is whether we can provide each frame separately at run time ..

Comment: Im looking for the same thing.But my situation is a bit more complex, user may pan-zoom the video.... Why should anyone down vote such a straight and challenging question?

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to implement that type of approach using the built-in movie player. But, if you are just going to loop through video frames stored in PNG files in a directory, that would not be too hard to implement. You could take a look at this code as a starting point. This source code is completely free and does what you need.

[PNGAnimatorDemo.zip](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex2)

If you want to do some more advanced stuff, take a look at the AVImageFrameDecoder class in the AVAnimator (google it to find out more).