# Optimization lot of UIImageView

Tags: ios, optimization, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I run into an optimization problem. I have a to display a lot of image a the same time on the screen (up to 150). These image are displayed like if it was a sphere, that can roll. [image: galaxy]

So far it run 60 fps on a new device, but there is some micro lags and I don't know what is the cause. The profiler tell me 59-60 fps but the problem is that the missing fps is visible and fell like a micro-slutter.
If I reduce the number of imageViews drastically, this problem disappear.
It doesn't seems to be gpu-limited, because I use something like 30% at most of the gpu, but the cpu never goes to more than 50% neither.

What could cause that/how can I detect the cause of this micro lag ? (the image are inited with contentOfFile)
What is the best solution to improve performance knowing that at least half of the image are not on the screen (other side of the sphere) ?

-Recycle UIImageViews

-Set not showed imageView to hidden (it's what i'm doing right now)

-Use rasterization layer (But since the size is changing everytime, it will re-render, right ?)

-Another magic solution that i'm not aware of.

If you want to try the app : 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oolala-instant-hangout-app/id972713282?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

1) The way those shapes are created is also important. The most performant way to do that (that's I'm aware of) would be to pre-render images with alpha channel.

2) There is also a "classic" jpeg [decompression problem](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/)

3) We used CALayer directly to render ~300 images in a UIScrollView on iPhone 4S screen without dropped frames. Might give it a shot.

```
_layer = [CALayer new];
_layer.contents = (id)_image.CGImage;
_layer.opaque = _opaque;
_layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

It was a long time ago and was used on iOS 5. You should probably disregard this suggestion unless you have a fast way to test it.

Comment: It's already prerendered, way better than adding a mask, as you said.  I'm gonna try. Does your method give better performance than a UIImageView ? If it's the case I wonder why.

Comment: >  Does your method give better performance than a UIImageView ?

Comment: I've updated my question. CALayer was used to improve NIAttributedLabel performance. It gave a huge performance boost over CGContextDrawImage. Now I'm starting to doubt whether it was faster then UIImageView, but I do believe we tested UIImageView too.

Comment: I found the problem, it was not a micro-lag but a problem in the inertia algorythm.
After a few test I can say that with 400 image on screen, there is no difference noticable with alpha-channel images. But i'm still at 60 fps on both so it's not reliable. Since you seem to know a lot about that, my (low) open gl skill told me that pow of 2 texture are easier to compute for the gpu, is that true ?

Comment: Presumably, when iOS wants to render image bitmap it would load it into an OpenGL texture. Then OpenGL would use some sort of interpolation algorithm to compute color for each fragment (pixel) to fill polygons that make image view. If your texture (image) size exactly matches image view size then no interpolation is required. OpenGL allows you to manually change interpolation algorithm. I'm not aware whether iOS takes advantage of this; or whether OpenGL optimises that for you automatically.

Comment: "that pow of 2 texture are easier" Sorry, I don't know that about that. I'm aware that OpenGL ES would not generate mipmaps if you use textures that are not power of 2. However, It should not affect drawing performance unless your image view size is more then twice smaller then displayed image (then one of the mipmaps is used).

Comment: Apple [do recommend](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html) to make your images the same size as its displayed size (image view size).

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do that because every image can be big (if in the center) or small (borders). Thank you for the help!

Comment: The root of the issue is the CPU time needed to decode the images before the data be sent to the screen. It does not matter if you use CoreGraphics or OpenGL, the image decompression time is the bottleneck. For more info about a complete solution to this problem, see this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545191/is-it-possible-to-generate-video-at-60-fps-and-play-it-back-at-60-fps/15540523#15540523